# Connecting eBGP and iBGP routers in Quagga

Tags: routing, bgp, ospf, loopback, quagga

I am trying to run intra and inter-domain routing using Quagga. I like to announce a prefix from AS7 and I like AS6 receive it and send it to AS2(as shown in the attached topology).

I know for intra topology I need to run OSPF. My question and my problem is about involving iBGP and eBGP routers in OSPF protocol. I mean, my guess is that I should use a public ip address for my eBGP routers. So do I need to run OSPF just on routers r3,r4,r10? Do I need to have a session between R6 and R5 or between R6 and R9? If I involve my eBGP routers in building my full mesh topology, then I need to connect R6 and for example R5 too. But as I am using their public ip addresses, then they can communicate without using the internal path. I am using their public ip addresses because I link AS7 could be able to talk to them.

Can you please help me to understand how can handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very confusing, and I think it is because you do not really understand some things. To get on the same page:

- Every router interface, including loopback interfaces, has its own
  address, each in a different network.
- eBGP is used between ASes.
- With eBGP, you will almost certainly use the interface addresses of
  the two directly-connected interfaces for the neighbor eBGP routers (it is possible, with complications, to
  use non-directly-connected interface addresses, but it is rare).
- iBGP is used inside a single AS.
- iBGP requires a full mesh between iBGP speakers (you can use a mitigation like route reflectors or confederations).
- An AS with an IGP makes it easy to connect iBGP to
  non-directly-connected interfaces, allowing the full mesh to be
  logical.
- An AS with an IGP and multiple physical paths between iBGP speakers
  should use loopbacks for the iBGP neighbor router addresses.

With that in mind, based on your drawing:

- Router 2 and Router 5 should peer via eBGP using their
  directly-connected interface addresses.
- Router 2 and Router 9 should peer via eBGP using their
  directly-connected interface addresses.
- Router 6 and Router 7 should peer via eBGP using their
  directly-connected interface addresses.
- AS6 should run an IGP among all the routers.
- Routers 5, 6, and 9 should have loopback addresses that are
  advertised by the IGP.
- Routers 5, 6, and 9 should peer via iBGP to each other using the
  loopback addresses.
- Routers 5 and 9 should have a direct link between them to prevent the ibgp peering between them from have to travel the entire AS.
- Unless AS8 wants to be a transit AS between AS2 and AS7, then you
  will need some type of filtering applied to prevent advertising AS2
  prefixes to AS9, and vice versa.